# How to assign particular intent.putextra() value to seperate alarm?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

How to get different extra for a particular alarm notification ?

My code to set alarm :-

```
fun setAlarm() {
        hour()
        min()
        text()
        for (item in HourArray) {
            for (item1 in MinArray) {
                for (item2 in TextArray) {
                    val hour: Int = item.toInt()
                    val min: Int = item1.toInt()
                    val text:String=item2
                    val calender = Calendar.getInstance()
                    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
                    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min)
                    calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
                    val am = context!!.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                    val intent = Intent(context, myBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("text",text)
                    intent.action = "com.tester.alarmmanager"

//                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                    var id: Long = calender.timeInMillis
                    val pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id.toInt(), intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingintent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My broadcast receiver class:-

```
 if(intent!!.action.equals("com.tester.alarmmanager"))
        {

            var b:Bundle=intent.extras
            var message=b.getString("text")
            //Toast.makeText(p0,"Hurreyyyy",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            var Notificationfind=Notifications()
            Notificationfind.Notify(p0!!,message,10)

        }
```

I want that when i set my first alarm the intent.PutExtra() values gets set and it gets updated with every call to it right now i am getting the same intent.extra value for every notification.

Comment: Have you checked the values of `id.toInt()` in the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` calls? Are you sure they're unique?

Comment: Yeah i think they are because everytime i set an alarm its value change so it must be unique right ?

Comment: Please do check. I'm not familiar with the details of Kotlin's `toInt()`, and the docs indicate that it "may involve rounding or truncation". You're going from a `Long` to an `Int`, so if it's truncating, you might be getting repeat values.

Comment: I am also saving hour,min,text in arraylist and then saving it to shared preference but let me try to generate a random numbet for id.

Comment: Why not just use an incrementing counter?

Comment: Let me try it give me a minute

Comment: Ok i gave it a try and when i set any notification it just show me the last value of the intent.extra instead of updating it like when i set 1st notification its working fine but in any notification after 2nd one i always see the 2nd notification text and i think its because of the for loops i am using.

Comment: Possibly. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, exactly, as far as setting these multiple alarms. However, if there's more than one element in `TextArray`, you're going to be setting multiple alarms for the same time. And in your Receiver, it appears that you're using the same ID for each `Notification`, so when those multiple alarms fire at the same time, it's going to immediately update the same `Notification`. At this point, about all I can suggest is to do some debugging/logging to make sure everything is as you're expecting, at both ends; i.e., in the set alarms, and the Receiver.

Comment: Use "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT"  instead of "PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT"